# Algorithm for polygon buffering/offsetting using edges with fixed lengths

Tags: algorithm, geometry, offset, bounding-box

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this
[image]

However, the inflated/deflated offset polygon can only have fixed amount of extra length. To compensate, the offset can be set in range, and the offset are kept minimum.

For example, the offset range is from 5 - 9 unit, and the offset will be kept as close to 5 as possible. The allowed extra length are 4, 6, 8. To achieve an offset of 5 unit from the original edge, the offset edge has to be 3 unit longer which is not in the allowed range. So that edge has to be 4/6/8 unit longer or/and offset further.

To summarize, these are what needed in the algorithm:

1 - The offset has to be in range of min -max, and be kept as close to minimum as possible.

2 - The extra length of the offset polygon edge can only be selected from a set

3 - The shape of the original polygon will only has right angles.

4 - Runtime is not an issue. The amount of edges of the original polygon will be less than 100

To visualize, let's imagine you are building a fence around a building. You only have fence "cells" with fixed width and depth, and have infinite amount of them to build the fence bounding lines.